# Create a PHP based API?

Tags: php, api, frameworks

Im looking for a framework (or a tutorial/website guideline) on how to build a php based api. The api would be accessed by a website and mobile apps. Here are the specification:

1. I need to be able to create php classes and have the methods
   accessible via a post request
2. authentication! Users need to log
   in (i guess that would be a class in itself) but most importantly,
   the app/system trying to access the api would first need to provide
   a valid access token

I looked into Zend, but im not sure if it can accomplish what im looking for. Can anyone point me in right direction?

Comment: I'd choose a REST implementation. For authorisation, you can choose OAuth, which is indeed token based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Symfony2 framework](http://symfony.com) has a lot of good support for REST APIs. The [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) is popular and can do most of the API work for you, and they just released a video of a [talk on REEST APIs](http://symfony.com/video/designing-http-interfaces-and-restful-web-services/English) from their recent developer conference in Paris.

For authentication, Symfony2 has user auth built in ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)). Most people also use the [FOSUSerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle), which adds in user registration, password recovery, etc.

Comment: Interesting. Would it be able to handle authentication?

Comment: It should be able to. Symfony supports basic security/authentication stuff out of the box, and has a bundle from the same group that can handle user registration, password recovery, etc. Not sure how it integrates into the REST bundle (never used the rest bundle myself) but it should be fairly simple.

Comment: Ok ill give it a shot, i hope its not too complicated to manage mobile app user sessions..

Answer (score 0):

You can use any frameworks. I prefer use Zend, another developers Symfony, another CakePHP etc. For example this article about how create REST Api use Zend
 http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2009/09/02/creating-a-php-rest-api-using-the-zend-framework/

You can googled simular article for other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Symfony 2 plus FOSUserBundle and FOSRestBundle. [Here](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/) you can find a great tutorial that helped me a lot.